# How to add legend on a lollypop graphic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this graphic and I would like to add a legend below the years, on the horizontal axis. I've tried several options but I can't see a single legend. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
ggplot(AIA) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=X, xend=X, y=A, yend=B), color="black") +
  geom_point( aes(x=X, y=A), color= "orange", size=4 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=X, y=B), color= "deepskyblue4", size=4 ) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c (0.95),
    panel.border = element_blank(),) +
  xlab("Innovaciones") +
  ylab("Años")
```

Data example

```
structure(list(X = c("Var. locales", "Var. Comerciales", "Comestibles", 
"Silvestres", "Fert. y abonos", "Análisis del suelo", "Manejo suelo", 
"Veg. Espontanea", "Métodos de siempra", "Plagas y enfermedades", 
"Desinfección", "Setos", "Refugios cajas nido", "Integración animal (otra)", 
"Composteras", "Maquinaria", "Eficiencia energética", "Riego", 
"Software y equipos", "Distribución"), A = c("1990", "1990", 
"1995", "1995", "1995", "1995", "2008", "1995", "1996", "2012", 
"2006", "1998", "2011", "1988", "1996", "1997", "1997", "1997", 
"2000", "2012"), B = c("2018", "2012", "2013", "1995", "2018", 
"2018", "2013", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2018", "2013", "2018", 
"2018", "1996", "2016", "1997", "2012", "2016", "2012")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by "add a legend below the years, on the horizontal axis". If you refer to what you wrote in "xlab", "ylab" then your code is right and it should appear. 
Or do you want to add another legend based on the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to reshape your data into long format, you can use `colour =` with each group name inside the `aes` call and add a `scale_color_manual`. To put the legend underneath the plot, use `theme(legend.position = "bottom")`

```
ggplot(AIA) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = X, xend = X, y = A, yend = B)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = A, color = "A"), size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = B, color = "B"), size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4"),
                     guide  = guide_legend(), 
                     name   = "Group") +
  xlab("Innovaciones") +
  ylab("Años")  +
  coord_flip()  +
  theme_light() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.border    = element_blank())
```

[image]